# Packaging a go binary and electron app together

Tags: go, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app (React) that communicates with a go binary over gRPC. I'm looking to package both binaries for distribution and I'm not entirely sure if there exists a way to package both the electron app and go binary into one single app (`.dmg` or otherwise)?

And how would I concurrently start both apps if they could be packaged into one binary for the end user?

Any help / advice in the right direction is appreciated!